# Is there a way to hide the map?

Tags: civilization-6

I would like to take a quick peek at the map as soon as it is created to see where the AI players are (single player mode), then hide the map again.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot, you can only see the map you are referring to at the post-game. So if you REALLY wanted to, you could save, surrender, go to post-game and see it, then reload the game to play. But it'd be taking away from the exploration aspect of the game which is considered to be one of the better parts of Civ games.

Comment: Despite the question, I totally agree about the exploration. I feel somewhat disappointed as the last map square is revealed.